# Composer. Как обновить все пакеты, кроме определенных?

Tags: php, composer

Имеется проект на Yii. Установлено несколько сторонних расширений в папке vendor.

Проблема в том, что в процессе разработки один кодер залез в vendor вместо того, чтобы переопределять классы и методы модуля. Я так понимаю, что при выполнении команды: `composer update` весь сторонний для модуля код исчезнет из vendor'a.

Выход очевиден: переписать по-нормальному. Но на время оставим как есть.

Собственно, как обновить другие пакеты, не трогая затронутые?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно зафиксировать текущую установленную версию пакета, тогда он не будет обновляться и изменения не затрутся.

Пример:

```
{
    "name": "The app",
    "require":{
        "monolog/monolog": "1.20.0.0",
        "phpoffice/phpexcel": "~1.8.0"
    }
}
```

Здесь monolog не будет обновляться если текущая установленная версия равна 1.20.0 (1.20.0.0 нормализованная версия)

phpoffice будет обновляться до версии <1.9.0

Текущую установленную версию можно найти в файле `vendor/composer/installed.json`